# Task "NETSdkError" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' > '$(NETCoreAppMaximumVersion)') was evaluated

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-6.0

I am getting an error in my Azure DevOps Pipeline as below when the task `DotNetCoreCLI@2` runs with the command `restore`.

```
2021-12-14T15:55:06.3451639Z    1:5>Target "_CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion" in file "/home/ziger/vsts-agents/adolin@pilos/_work/_tool/dotnet/sdk/6.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets" from project "/home/ziger/vsts-agents/adolin@pilos/_work/60/s/src/Data.csproj" (target "CollectPackageReferences" depends on it):
2021-12-14T15:55:06.3453249Z        Task "NETSdkError" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)' > '$(NETCoreAppMaximumVersion)') was evaluated as ('6.0' > '6.0').
2021-12-14T15:55:06.3453980Z    1:5>Done building target "_CheckForUnsupportedNETCoreVersion" in project "Intranet.Hub.Licensehandling.Data.csproj".
2021-12-14T15:55:06.3455558Z        Target "_CheckForEolTargetFrameworks" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_EolNetCoreTargetFrameworkVersions->AnyHaveMetadataValue('Identity', '$(_TargetFrameworkVersionWithoutV)'))' and '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETCoreApp' and '$(CheckEolTargetFramework)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('false' and '.NETCoreApp' == '.NETCoreApp' and 'true' == 'true').
```

And here is the template I used for my pipeline (It is not complete, pasting only restore task here).

```
parameters:
  - name: azureSubscription
    type: string
  - name: webAppName
    type: string
  - name: sourceBranchTrigger
    type: string

stages:
  - stage: build_stage
    displayName: "Build"
    jobs:
      - job: build_job
        steps:
          - task: UseDotNet@2
            displayName: "Install .NET Core SDK"
            inputs:
              version: 6.0.x
              performMultiLevelLookup: true
              includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: "Dotnet Restore"
            inputs:
              command: "restore"
              feedsToUse: "select"
              feedRestore: "Admin/Admin"
              projects: "**/*.csproj"
              includeNuGetOrg: true
```

Have you ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this just by replacing the version to `6.x` instead of `6.0.x` in the `UseDotNet@2` task.

```
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: "Install .NET Core SDK"
    inputs:
      version: 6.x
      performMultiLevelLookup: true
      includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: "Dotnet Restore"
    inputs:
      command: "restore"
      feedsToUse: "select"
      feedRestore: "Admin/Admin"
      projects: "**/*.csproj"
      includeNuGetOrg: true
```